# How to reference a cell in sheet using the sheetname written in cell

Tags: excel, reference, excel-indirect

I have "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3".... as my headers in cells A1, B1, C1....

I also have "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3".... sheet names.

In the second row, I would like to reference to corresponding sheets' cells. For example in cell A2, I gives have tried indirect function `INDIRECT(A1)` but it gives #ref error. I actually want to reference sheet Week 1, but all I can imagine is this function `=SHEETS(INDIRECT(A1))`. Of course I have the same error again.

I want to reference to sheet "Week 1" cell A2, by using current sheet's A1 value ("Week 1") in the formula.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the function incorrectly. The proper usage is `=INDIRECT("A1")` by using "".

As for your questions, to be able to reference a sheet name by using cell value, you need to use [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) function, not [SHEET](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/SHEET-function-44718b6f-8b87-47a1-a9d6-b701c06cff24) function. Sheet function returns the number of sheets.

The proper function you are looking for is `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,1,,,A1))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the sheet name in brackets in the `INDIRECT`.

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A2")
```

For a different workbook, you use brackets:

```
=INDIRECT("["&A1&"]A2")
```

So you can combine them:

```
=INDIRECT("["&A1&"]"&A2&"!B1")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was for a different workbook. You need a `!` for a sheet name.